# How do I make an Image appear in Android

Tags: java, android

I set the image on the graphical layout, but now I am actually trying to make it appear, so far I have this

```
ImageView redPlayer = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.redCounter);
```

but it is saying redPlayer is unused so How do I make it appear?

Comment: Does it appear in your GUI?

Comment: Is it a warning from the IDE? Did you try to run your app and see if the image appears?

Comment: It appears in the GUI, No I did not run it, should it appear?

Comment: its not appearing when I run it

Comment: have you set a background or src attribute for the ImageView in your xml code?

Answer (score 2):

you must than assign a bitmap to this ImageView, use :

```
ImageView redPlayer = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.redCounter);
redPlayer.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

or you can set a drawable from resources , use :

```
ImageView redPlayer = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.redCounter);
redPlayer.setImageResource(bitmap);
```

Answer (score 1):

> but it is saying redPlayer is unused

This is just a warning like with any variable. It is letting you know you haven't used it such as calling a method on it. You don't need to declare or initialize it in your Java code for it to appear. If you have given it an image to show in the xml then it should show when you run the program.

You need to give it an image. You can do this in xml with something like `android:src="@drawable/someDrawable"` or `android:background="@drawable/someDrawable"`. You can also do it in your Java code with different methods depending on what you need.

[See the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource%28int%29) for the different methods.

Comment: I am trying to make it appear in a custom view, I have implemented the customview on to the activity

Comment: @user3299420, so post the code for the custom view if you want us to fix it. Otherwise like codeMagic says, the image will appear without any problem and the warning won't prevent you from compiling and running the code you have now.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great tutorial example of using ImageView in Android
http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/imageview/android-imageview-example/

The unused comment from the IDE is just saying that you have not done anything with the image view you assigned (to just display it you do not need to use it in the activity).

Hope that helps.